# C# Add value to a texbox based on the Combobox selection

Tags: c#, winforms

We have selected a value from a combobox and need the related information in the textbox.
The following code does not work for the same.

```
   private void itemcode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            string selected = (string)itemcode.SelectedItem;
            SqlConnection conn3 = new SqlConnection(connString);
            conn3.Open();
            //For Redundency Checking Code of Supplier id.
            string iname = "select Itemname from Items where Itemcode='" +  
                            itemcode.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
            SqlCommand cmdRedun1 = new SqlCommand(iname, conn3);
            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmdRedun1.ExecuteReader();
            dr1.Read();
            itemname.Text = dr1["Itemname"].ToString();
            dr1.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? textbox is not assigning or selected item is not populating or something else

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Also, why would you use `itemcode.SelectedItem.ToString()` if you saved it in `selected` before? Have you tried debugging to watch the variables?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: i can just guess, please check postback issue once. If it is ok then move forward.

Answer (score 1):

First Check your Item Value Of Combo box , and then create your query with StringFormat 
 for example :

```
 string iname = String.Format("select Itemname from Items where Itemcode='{0}'",
 itemcode.SelectedItem.ToString()) ;
```

//-- then please check out below code :

```
SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
SqlConn.Open();
SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(" Your Select....", SqlConn);
SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataReader r = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
//----need this 
while (r.Read())                
itemname.Text =  string.IsNullOrEmpty(r["Itemname"].ToString()) ?  
  string.Empty : r["Itemname"].ToString();           
 r.Close();
 if (SqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
      SqlConn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ExecuteScalar instead of SqlDataReader.